# Changelog path resolving in Liquibase maven plugin

Tags: java, database, maven, migration, liquibase

I've got one problem with liquibase-maven-plugin 4.2.2. If I specify the path to logs like it was before

```
changeLogFile= classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

I'm getting an error

> Error Reading Changelog File: Found 2 files that match classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml: jar:file:/Users/macbook/IdeaProjects/geek-study-eshop/shop-database/target/shop-database-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml, file:/Users/macbook/IdeaProjects/geek-study-eshop/shop-database/target/classes/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

I understand the reason for this error and it possible to resolve it by changing `changeLogFile` to `target/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`. But in this case, I will have `target\` prefix in filenames stored in `DATABASECHANGELOG` table. But I don't want that for some reasons. I want all file names there to be with prefix `db/changelog/...` or `classpath:db/changelog/...`. Is that possible to do that somehow without using `logicFilePath` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! There is no way to change `liquibase-maven-plugin` behavior but it's possible to change maven phase on which we run `liquibase:diff` command. Simply use `mvn clean compile liquibase:diff`! We are doing diff after compilation and resource movement but before the jar packaging.